# Adding gridlines to each subplot pie chart in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 2d array with 8 sub arrays. I want to plot each of the array in pie charts as shown:

[image]

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 2,figsize=(15, 15))

axes[0,0].pie(counts_list[0])
axes[0,1].pie(counts_list[1])

axes[1,0].pie(counts_list[2])
axes[1,1].pie(counts_list[3])

axes[2,0].pie(counts_list[4])
axes[2,1].pie(counts_list[5])

axes[3,0].pie(counts_list[6])
axes[3,1].pie(counts_list[7])

plt.show()
```

What I have achieved with this code:

[image]

Now I have tried every possible answer solution from SO and the internet, added grids like axes[0][0].grid() to each, added

```
plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = True
```

but for some reason the grid lines are not coming up on the pie charts. How do I solve this?

Any guidance in the correct direction is appreciated. Thanks. Also if the code for the arrays is required, please let me know in the comments.

I have plotted the actual pie charts, just need to add the gridlines and the color scheme.

Comment: You can find examples in the [references](https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/stats/pie.html#sphx-glr-plot-types-stats-pie-py). Disable styles and add ax.grid().

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = [32, 45, 67, 12, 1]

ax.pie(data)

# turn on frame
ax.set_frame_on(b=True)

# create locations of grid points
xrange = ax.get_xlim()
ngrids = 7
dx = (xrange[1] - xrange[0]) / ngrids
gridvals = [xrange[0] + (dx / 2) + i * dx for i in range(ngrids)]

# set grid location
ax.set_yticks(gridvals, minor=False)
ax.set_xticks(gridvals, minor=False)

# set tick labels (to be from 1 to 7)
ax.set_xticklabels([f"{i}" for i in range(1, ngrids + 1)])
ax.set_yticklabels([f"{i}" for i in range(1, ngrids + 1)])

# turn grid on
ax.yaxis.grid(True, which="major")
ax.xaxis.grid(True, which="major")
```

To use the `Blues` color map, see the example [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/stats/pie.html#sphx-glr-plot-types-stats-pie-py).

Comment: That's great. So I need to repeat these steps are all the 8 pie charts, is that correct? Also, thanks for the Blues color map link.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you'll have to do this for each of the 8 `axes`, although you could put in a for loop.

Comment: I implemented it. All looking perfect, added the linespacing, edge color etc as well. It is looking the exact copy of the one I was required to get. Thanks a lot. One last thing is that the x-axis is 2 4 6 but in my case it is 1 to 7. So I did ax.set_xticklabels([f"{i}" for i in range(2, ngrids + 1, 2)]) and the xticks are 2 4 6 but there are 4 empty ticks now after 6. I am guessing this is because of where we are assigning gridvals to xticks. Not sure how to get 2 4 6 only for the x axis.

Comment: I managed to do it. Thanks for the help.